# How to pass -std=c99 to g++?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, g++

My cpp file includes C header that has a enumerator with comma at the end. As a result g++ produces warning:

> warning: comma at end of enumerator list

How can I tell g++ to use -std=c99 for that cpp file? That is, how can I avoid this warning?

I already tried: -std=c99 but it resulted in: "cc1plus: warning: command line option "-std=c99" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++"

Note: the inclusion of C headers is surrounded with extern "C" command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.  `g++` compiles C++, not C.  A C header included in a C++ source file still has to follow C++ rules, even with `extern "C"`.  For example, the header cannot use `class` as an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

`#include` works by simply inserting the text of the included file in the position where the `#include` line occurs. The result of preprocessing is a single text file which is then sent to the compiler, and you cannot change the language in the middle of the file.

Since your cpp file is being compiled as C++ code, the headers it includes will be as well. `extern "C"` does not change the language; it simply tells the C++ compiler that the functions declared within use the C calling convention.